# Sequential Order of Puranas

Tags: scripture, puranas

We all know that there are 18 puranas in the Hindu mythology. The puranas were composed one after the another. What is the sequential order of the puranas, from the first to the last?

Comment: Do you want actual chronological order (each Purana is composed in different Kalpas according to Matsya Purana)? or do you want chronological order of Puranas recounted by Vyasa? or Chronological order of Puranas written during Gupta Period?

Comment: @TheDestroyer do you have chronological order of Puranas written in Gupta period...?

Comment: @Tezz No. I want to make OP clear which part he is interested.

Comment: @TheDestroyer: I want the chronological order in Vyasa recounted.

Comment: @Pandya, do u want a script to automatically remove the mythology tag ?

Comment: @ram Actually we need to check each and every question before fixing the tags. Read [the pinned message in chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54625098#54625098) for more information.

Answer (score 13):

The order of the appearance of different Purans is given in the **Matsya Puran Chapter 53** as narrated by Suta.

[image]

According to the text the order of the appearance of the Purans is as follows:

> 1. Brahma Puran
> 2. Padma Puran
> 3. Vishnu Puran
> 4. Vayu Puran
> 5. Bhagvat Puran
> 6. Naradiya Puran
> 7. Markandeya Puran
> 8. Agni Puran
> 9. Bhavishya Puran
> 10. Brahmavaivarta Puran
> 11. Linga Puran
> 12. Varah Puran
> 13. Skanda Puran
> 14. Vaman Puran
> 15. Kurma Puran
> 16. Matsya Puran
> 17. Garud Puran
> 18. Brahmand Puran

Comment: But time is cyclic. I want to know how this order is given, I mean based on yugas or something?

Comment: And what about Devi bhagavata purana?

Comment: @KrishnShweta these are the only 18 Purans mentioned in this text. From what I could understand this order is chronological as per the different Kalpas and Manvantars.

Comment: @KrishnShweta Bhagavata Purana in list is Srimad Bagavatam for Vaishnavas and Devi Bhagavatam for Shaktas.

Comment: Nice answer . Just for info. - Here is another list from Shreemad Bhagvat Purana - https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/7/23-24

Comment: here shiva purana is missing !

Answer (score 7):

Srimad Bhagavata Purana lists sequential order of Puranas:

[SB 12.13.4-8](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/13/4-9)

- The **Brahma Purāṇa** consists of ten thousand verses,
- The **Padma Purāṇa** consists of fifty-five thousand verses,
- Śrī **Viṣhṇu Purāṇa** consists of twenty-three thousand verses,
- The **Śhiva Purāṇa** consists of twenty-four thousand verses
- The **Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam** consists of eighteen thousand verses,
- The **Narada Purana** has twenty-five thousand verses,
- The **Mārkaṇḍeya Purāṇa** has nine thousand verses,
- The **Agni Purāṇa** has fifteen thousand four hundred verses,
- The **Bhaviṣya Purāṇa** has fourteen thousand five hundred verses,
- The **Brahma-vaivarta Purāṇa** has eighteen thousand verses,
- The **Liṅga Purāṇa** has eleven thousand verses,
- The **Varāha Purāṇa** contains twenty-four thousand verses,
- The **Skanda Purāṇa** contains eighty-one thousand one hundred verses,
- The **Vāmana Purāṇa** contains ten thousand verses,
- The **Kūrma Purāṇa** contains seventeen thousand verses,
- The **Matsya Purāṇa** contains fourteen thousand verses,
- The **Garuḍa Purāṇa** contains nineteen thousand verses and
- The **Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa** contains twelve thousand verses.